# Connection error in Python TCP Chat Server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

So i was following along with the NeuralNine TCP chat in python tutorial and all was fine but then a problem occured not on the server side but on the client side

This is the server side code:

```
    1 import socket
    2 from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
    3
    4 signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
    5
    6 host = '127.0.0.1'  # localhost
    7 port = 55555
    8
    9 server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   10 server.bind((host, port))
   11 server.listen()
   12
   13 clients = []
   14 nicknames = []
   15
   16
   17 def broadcast(message):
   18 ┊   for client in clients:
   19 ┊   ┊   client.send(message)
   20
   21
   22 def handle(client):
   23 ┊   while True:
   24 ┊   ┊   try:
   25 ┊   ┊   ┊   message = client.recv(1024)
   26 ┊   ┊   ┊   broadcast(message)
   27 ┊   ┊   except:
   28 ┊   ┊   ┊   index = client.index(client)
   29 ┊   ┊   ┊   clients.remove(client)
   30 ┊   ┊   ┊   client.close()
   31 ┊   ┊   ┊   nickname = nicknames[index]
   32 ┊   ┊   ┊   nicknames.remove(nickname)
   33 ┊   ┊   ┊   broadcast(f'{nickname} left the chat'.encode('ascii'))
   34 ┊   ┊   ┊   break
   35
   36
   37 def recieve():
   38 ┊   while True:
   39 ┊   ┊   client, address = server.accept()
   40 ┊   ┊   print(f'Connected with {str(address)}')
   41 ┊   ┊
   42 ┊   ┊   client.send('NICK'.encode('ascii'))
   43 ┊   ┊   nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
   44 ┊   ┊   nicknames.append(nickname)
   45 ┊   ┊   clients.append(clienprint(f'Nickname of the client is {nickname}')
   48 ┊   ┊   broadcast(f'{nickname} joined the chat'.encode('ascii'))
   49 ┊   ┊   client.send('Connected to the server'.encode('ascii'))
   50 ┊   ┊
   51 ┊   ┊   thread = threading.thread(target=handle, args=(client))
   52 ┊   ┊   thread.start()
   53
   54
   55 print('Server is Listening.....')
   56 recieve()
```

After running it i get the following output:

`Server is Listening...`

Then i run client.py in another terminal
it asks for nickname but then this happens

```
Choose a nickname: bob
An error occured
```

and then the program would not exit for some reason
Then when i look at the server.py log this is visible

```
Server is Listening.....
Connected with ('127.0.0.1', 43386)
Nickname of the client is
```

If anyone could please help i would highly appreciate it

btw here is the code for client.py

```
import socket
    2 import threading
    3
    4 nickname = input("Choose a nickname: ")
    5
    6
    7
W   8 client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)     ■ E303 too many blank lines (3)
    9 client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 55555))
   10
   11
   12 def recieve():
   13 ┊   while True:
   14 ┊   ┊   try:
   15 ┊   ┊   ┊   message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
   16 ┊   ┊   ┊   if message == "NICK":
   17 ┊   ┊   ┊   ┊   client.send(nickname).encode('ascii')
   18 ┊   ┊   ┊   else:
   19 ┊   ┊   ┊   ┊   print(message)
   20 ┊   ┊
W  21 ┊   ┊   except:     ■ E722 do not use bare 'except'
   22 ┊   ┊   ┊   print("An error occurred")
   23 ┊   ┊   ┊   client.close()
   24 ┊   ┊   ┊   break
   25
   26
   27 def write():
   28 ┊   while True:
   29 ┊   ┊   message = f'{nickname}: {input("")}'
   30 ┊   ┊   client.send(message.encode('ascii'))
   31
   32
   33 recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target=recieve)
   34 recieve_thread.start()
   35
   36 write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
   37 write_thread.start()
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to remove the line numbers from your code? With them, we can't copy and paste your code to debug it.

Comment: `■ E722 do not use bare 'except'`: as the linter is telling you, `except:` is evil. Never write that. Replace that with `except Exception as e: print(e)` (then when you find what exact error you want to catch, replace `Exception` with that exact error), then run the code again to get an error message.

Comment: TCP is not message-based.  Any tutorial that treats send/recv as 1:1 messages is wrong. Any tutorial that teaches bare except is wrong.  Find a better tutorial.